# C++ вызов функции каждую секунду

Tags: c++

Нужно создать функцию, которая будет вызываться каждую секунду и выполнять определенные действия. Без sleep, ибо программа должна выполнять и другой функционал.

Comment: Ну, или используйте таймер, или отдельный поток (что надежнее :))

Comment: У вас в тегах часто есть Qt. В этот раз без него нужно?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb думаю обычный C++ код, подойдет и для Qt. Разве нет?

Comment: А другой функционал, это какой. у вас есть какой то цикл обработки или еще что то подобное. вот в него и можете встроить проверку времени и периодический вызов.

Comment: @Insider да, но у Qt могут быть собственные средства для этой задачи. `std::thread` появился только в C++11. (Это давно, но всё ещё стоит иметь в виду, к сожалению.)

Comment: @Mike получаю TCP пакеты и обробатываю их. Не хотелось бы перемешывать.

Comment: @D-side хорошо, посмотрю )

Comment: tcp пакеты получаете как ? у вас там есть какой то цикл с select (или epoll) вот в нем таймаут ставите на время которое осталось до следующего вызова функции

Comment: @Mike получаю я их через connect вызовом других функций

Comment: @Insider, в qt есть [такое](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer)

Comment: Если у вас вызовы tcp стека блокирующие, то только отдельный поток.

Comment: Такие вещи делаются через таймеры, в C++ таймеров нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так пойдет?

```
template<class Func, class ...Args>
void run(int msec, Func func, Args &&...args){
    auto endless = [=](Args &&...args){
        while(true){
            func(args...);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(msec));
        }
    };

    std::thread thread(endless, args...);

    thread.detach();
}
```

Функция запускает поток, который вызывает вашу функцию с заданным интервалом и параметрами.

[Пример](http://cpp.sh/3nqob)

Comment: Да отличный пример. Благодарю.